# Triggers in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and I am currently working on triggers but am stuck at one point.

I have two tables Student and Room.

Room id is the primary key in Room and foreign key in Student.

If I am inserting in Student, then it should check in Room whether the new data exist or not.

This is a foreign key check constraint. I hope anyone can help me with it

Comment: Why do you need a trigger when you have already a foreign key constraint?

Comment: I am sorry, I have to drop the foreign key constraint and then execute it with trigger

Comment: Why do you "have" to drop the foreign key? That is *much* more efficient than a trigger

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your code and I dont get the meaning, but I can answer generally.

In PostgreSQL a trigger is normally defined in **two** steps:

1. Define a **trigger function** using the *CREATE FUNCTION*
2. Bind this created trigger function to a table using *CREATE TRIGGER*

A trigger function is a common function, except that is has a return value type *trigger* (in addition, it does not take any arguments).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_function() 
  RETURNS trigger 
AS $$ ... $$;
```

binding:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name 
   AFTER INSERT ON table_name 
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_function();
```

In addition, please also consult the excellent PG documentation at [PostgreSQL 9.4 Triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/triggers.html)